# FullCalendar (1.6) difficulty updating existing event on calendar with renderEvent

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using an older version of fullCalendar (1.6.4) with mostly success.  I've got a UI that has the ability to add new events to the calendar, and then edit them inline.  I'm running into problems when I try to then update the calendar with the modified event object.  I'm only running into this problem however with dynamically added events, I can apparently reload the page and update events that fullCalendar adds initially just fine.

The problem seems very related to how the **event.source** property works.  When the property is null on the event, fullCalendar pushes a new instance of the event onto the "cache" object, even if the event otherwise exists on the calendar already.  I'm not sure why or how this works. For whatever reason though, I then end up with duplicate instances of the event on the calendar day.

```
// code directly from fullCalendar 1.6.4
function renderEvent(event, stick) {
       console.log('renderEvent',event)
            normalizeEvent(event);
            if (!event.source) {
                    if (stick) {
                            stickySource.events.push(event);
                            event.source = stickySource;
                    }
                    cache.push(event);
    }
    reportEvents(cache);
```

}

So, in cases that are a pure edit of an existing calendar item, I make sure the source value is set and not lost/nulled anywhere.  Even if worst case it does the below and sets it to an empty object.  (Note, this may be a cause of my problems, I just don't know enough about full calendar).  Sometimes I even have to force it to be {}, otherwise it has multiple items in source and I again end up with duplicate calendar entries after updating.

```
 calEvent.source = calEvent.source ? calEvent.source : {};
```

I then update my existing calendar with a call to renderEvent.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', calEvent, true);
```

Unfortunately, I'm running into the case where the new calEvent sent to renderEvent is updated, and it does not update the instance on the calendar.  This may be because of the source field?  And it only happens for newly dynamically added events.

Can someone assist about how to properly edit events?  And how this source field should properly be used.

Comment: Instead of calling renderEvent after changing event data, have you tried [updateEvent](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvent/)?

Comment: Completely unaware of that obviously better approach! Add it as a solution and i'll give you credit.  It helped a lot, though sometimes i need to call it twice in a row to make it take effect.